# calculating mutation frequencies for every gene

Tags: python, mutations, pandas

I have a dataset for mutation data and I want to calculate mutation frequencies across all genes

**df** (This is only the small subset of data)

```
Gene name   Sample id   MUTATION_ID Mutation Description
ARID1B  2719660 171258500   Substitution - Missense
ARID1B  2719659     
ARID1B  2719661 171258501   Substitution - Missense
ARID1B  2719662     
ARID1B  2719663 171258501   Substitution - Nonsense
CD58    2878555 110346783   Substitution - Nonsense
CD58    2877956     
CD58    2878557     
CD58    2877958 110346784   Substitution - Nonsense
CD58    2878559 110346785   Substitution - Nonsense
CD58    2877960     
MRE11   2861617 123320443   Substitution - coding silent
MRE12   2861617 123320444   Substitution - coding 
MRE13   2861617     
MRE14   2861617 123320445   Substitution - coding silent
MRE15   2861617     
MRE16   2861617 123320446   Substitution - coding
```

The formula for calculating the mutation is

`Positives ÷ (Positives + Negatives) x 100`

where,

`Positives`  = No of samples where `MUTATION_ID` is present

`Negative` = No of samples `MUTATION_ID` for the sample

I want to calculate mutation frequency for every gene in the `column_1:Gene name` with python script

I tried the following code

```
df = df.groupby("Gene name").count()
Positives = df["MUTATION_ID"]
Negatives = df["Sample id"] - df["MUTATION_ID"] 
df['Mutation_Frequency'] = Positives / (Positives + Negatives) * 100
```

Comment: Are your fields tab separated? They probably have to be since you have spaces in the description field. And what are those extra `-`? Is that a separate field with no header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine. The only issue is you'd put \s characters in-between the column header names. I've place an additional "mutation_frequency" column because thats how I'd do it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/pathtodir/test/bioinfo.csv',sep="\s",engine='python')
df = df.groupby("Genename").count()
df['Mutation_Frequency1'] = ((df["MUTATION_ID"] / (df["Sampleid"] + (df["Sampleid"] - df["MUTATION_ID"]))) * 100).round(2)
df['Mutation_Frequency2'] = (df["MUTATION_ID"] / df["Sampleid"])*100
df.drop(['Description', 'Mutation'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

| - | Sampleid | MUTATION_ID | Mutation_Frequency1 | Mutation_Frequency2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARID1B | 5 | 3 | 42.86 | 60.0 |
| CD58 | 6 | 3 | 33.33 | 50.0 |
| MRE11 | 1 | 1 | 100.00 | 100.0 |
| MRE12 | 1 | 1 | 100.00 | 100.0 |
| MRE13 | 1 | 0 | 0.00 | 0.0 |
| MRE14 | 1 | 1 | 100.00 | 100.0 |
| MRE15 | 1 | 0 | 0.00 | 0.0 |
| MRE16 | 1 | 1 | 100.00 | 100.0 |